# Python: Need Help Debugging Relatively Simple Function

Tags: python

Below is the simple function I am working on.

When I execute the 3 tests called out as examples in the specification, I get an error on the 3rd test (crane to bane).

I know that the error is specifically in the `after` variable as I would expect that to just be `ane` and instead, I am seeing `rane` printed when I run the test.

I have tried the following and each time, these changes have caused unintentional errors in the first two tests called out in the specification.

```py
after = word[pos:]
after = word[pos-1:]
```

```py
def replace_first(word,a,b):
    """
    Returns: a copy of word with the FIRST instance of a replaced by b
    
    Example: replace_first('crane','a','o') returns 'crone'
    Example: replace_first('poll','l','o') returns 'pool'
    Example: replace_first('crane','cr','b') returns 'bane'
    
    Parameter word: The string to copy and replace
    Precondition: word is a string
    
    Parameter a: The substring to find in word
    Precondition: a is a valid substring of word
    
    Parameter b: The substring to use in place of a
    Precondition: b is a string
    """
    pos = introcs.find_str(word,a)
    print(pos)
    
    before = word[:pos]
    print(before)
    
    after  = word[pos+1:]
    print(after)
    
    result = before+b+after
    print(result)
    
    return result
```

Here is the output of the test when I run it:

```
Testing replace_first
2
cr
ne
crone
2
po
l
pool
0

rane
brane
assert_equals: expected 'bane' but instead got 'brane'
Line 25 of tests.py: introcs.assert_equals('bane', result)
Quitting with Error
```

Comment: Perhaps this is for practice, perhaps it's not. If it's the case that it is not, [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) allows an easy way to accomplish this. Example: `"hello world".replace("l", "x", 1)` outputs `'hexlo world'`.

Comment: I should have specified - yes, this is for practice for a class I am taking and I've been stuck for while on this.  It seems like it should be straightforward and I'm just lost.  :(

Comment: Roger that. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working for `crane` to `bane` is because you are not taking into account the length of the input of `a` (in this case `cr`, therefore length of 2) here:

```py
    ...
    after  = word[pos+1:]
    ...
```

What's going on is that `pos = introcs.find_str(word, a)` gives you index of *where input `a` **starts***, and you are assuming that `a` is always of the length `1` when you do `+1`. Instead, it should be:

```py
    ...
    after  = word[pos+len(a):]
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Felipe!  Yes, I knew that it was broken bc it was not picking up the full length of my input string.  Thank you for the quick response and the very clear solution.

Comment: My pleasure. You were on the right track with all of the print statements and finding _where_ the bug was. Glad I was of help - best of luck.